# Using WHERE in PROC SQL Error

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Currently I'm trying to filter the output I have to display only products which have discounts greater than or equal to 60%. The variable discount lists all their values in the format such as 50%, 60% etc.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT discount.Product_ID,Product_Name,Start_Date,End_Date,Discount
 FROM Final.discount AS d, Final.product_dim AS p
 WHERE d.Product_ID=p.Product_ID
 AND Discount >= 60%;
QUIT;
```

I dont know why this isn't working, but the error from the log tells me that the percent sign isnt recognized? How would I fix this to get the output I desire?

Comment: What datatype is Discount? If you're storing values as 50%, 60% (rather than 50, 60, etc) - is it a varchar / string datatype?

Comment: Agree with CoolBots...run a proc contents on the data set and find out what your variable is...you can potentially just wrap in quotes if it's a character - '60%', or just call out the number if its formatted as a number - 60

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the variable is numeric with the `PERCENTw.d` format applied (so likely `PERCENT5.` given your display), you would write it like so:

```
Discount >= 0.6;
```

The `PERCENTw.d` format displays numbers between 0 and 1 as 0% - 100%.

If your variable is character, then you would probably need to convert it to a number first (as `'100%' > '60%'` is false).

```
input(Discount, PERCENT5.) >= 0.6
```

This is well covered in Rick Wicklin's blog post on [the Do Loop](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/08/10/percent-formats.html).